# Optimizing Python KD Tree Searches

Tags: numpy, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

Scipy (http://www.scipy.org/) offers two KD Tree classes; the KDTree and the cKDTree.

The cKDTree is much faster, but is less customizable and query-able than the KDTree (as far as I can tell from the docs).

**Here is my problem:**
I have a list of 3million 2 dimensional (X,Y) points. I need to return all of the points within a distance of X units from every point.

With the KDtree, there is an option to do just this: `KDtree.query_ball_tree()` It generates a list of lists of all the points within X units from every other point. HOWEVER: this list is enormous and quickly fills up my virtual memory (*about 744 million items long*).

**Potential solution #1:** Is there a way to parse this list into a text file as it is writing?

**Potential solution #2:** I have tried using a for loop (for every point in the list) and then finding that single point's neighbors within X units by employing: `KDtree.query_ball_point()`. HOWEVER: this takes forever as it needs to run the query millions of times. Is there a cKDTree equivalent of this KDTree tool?

**Potential solution #3:** Beats me, anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From scipy 0.12 on, both KD Tree classes have feature parity. Quoting its [announcement](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2013-April/034427.html):

> ## cKDTree feature-complete
>
> Cython version of KDTree, cKDTree, is now feature-complete.  Most
>   operations (construction, query, query_ball_point, query_pairs,
>   count_neighbors and sparse_distance_matrix) are between 200 and 1000
>   times faster in cKDTree than in KDTree.  With very minor caveats,
>   cKDTree has exactly the same interface as KDTree, and can be used as a
>   drop-in replacement.

Comment: Ah that would be excellent. I don't have any skill/experience with compiling from source so maybe I will look into that. Otherwise, unless another solution is posted, I will wait for the new release of scipy.

Comment: @Dlinet Version 0.12 was released last month.

Comment: For anyone arriving at this answer in present times (2022), starting from SciPy v1.6.0 `cKDTree` is *"functionally identical to KDTree"* with matching performance (see [Note](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`KDTree.query_ball_point`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html) instead. It takes a single point, *or array of points*, and produces the points within a given distance of the input point(s).

You can use this function to perform batch queries. Give it, say, 100000 points at a time, and then write the results out to a file. Something like this:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 100000
for i in xrange(0, len(pts), BATCH_SIZE):
    neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(pts[i:i+BATCH_SIZE], X)
    # write neighbours to a file...
```

Comment: Unless I am understanding you wrong, I think that is exactly what I have listed as potential solution #2 no? The problem with that method as far as I can tell is it takes forever.

Comment: What you suggested was to loop over every single point. Here, what I suggested is to use it in a "batch" mode, so you spend less time iterating.

Comment: Ah interesting, I will look into this. I have never used "batches" before. do you suggest any particular resources for learning more about batches?